# What is the most performant way to ensure thread safety in a Spring component?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring

Suppose I have the following class:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {

    public Double calculateNodeSum(Node node) {
        Double sum = node.getAmount();
        for (Node child : node.getChildren()) {
            if (!visited(child)) {
                markNodeVisited(child);
                sum += calculateNodeSum(child);
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Assumptions:

- Assume that the node graph is not being modified while any of these calculations are occurring.

(Some methods such as `visited` and `markNodeVisited` have been left out).  My question is this:
What is the best way (in terms of performance) to modify this class such that my calculateNodeSum method is thread safe?  I can think of several:

1. add a `private final Object lock = new Object();` field to the class, and synchronize the calculateNodeSum method using this lock object.  Track the visited nodes using a class member field `private Set<Node> visitedNodes`.  This would also require us to clear the `visitedNodes` we're tracking each time the method is called.
2. modify the calculateNodeSum method so that we initially create, and then pass a `visitedNodes` local variable of type `Set<Node>` around to track the visited nodes
3. use Spring's `@Scope` annotation to manage scope (`request` scope might work, as long as there aren't multiple threads per request calling this method)
4. some other solution that I haven't thought of

Comment: Define what you mean by thread-safe.  I'm not being facetious.  What is the correct behavior you are expecting, what might other threads be doing while you call this, and what affects should that have ... or not have.

Comment: Sure.  By thread-safe, I mean that I don't want my set of visited nodes to be corrupted.  Example: MyComponent is instantiated as a singleton bean (the Spring default).  I have two threads A and B.  Thread A calls calculateNodeSum with a tree structure that has one billion nodes.  A fraction of a second later, Thread B calls calculateNodeSum with a subset of the nodes such that there is overlap in the nodes in thread A and thread B.  I want the sum to be calculated correctly on each thread.  Without some strategy for doing this safely, my list of visited nodes will be written by both threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is to NOT keep any state in the @Component, so no locking is needed. So state is only kept in local variables which are passed to other methods as arguments. So, I guess I would go for option 2.

Answer (score 0):

The heart of the question is what you mean by thread-safe.

> By thread-safe, I mean that I don't want my set of visited nodes to be corrupted.

I understand that.  However, the code as given doesn't mutate the graph.  (OK ... `markNodeVisited(child)` might do ... but if it does then your algorithm is inherently non-reentrant which moots the following ...)

> Example: MyComponent is instantiated as a singleton bean (the Spring default). I have two threads A and B. Thread A calls calculateNodeSum with a tree structure that has one billion nodes. A fraction of a second later, Thread B calls calculateNodeSum with a subset of the nodes such that there is overlap in the nodes in thread A and thread B. I want the sum to be calculated correctly on each thread. Without some strategy for doing this safely, my list of visited nodes will be written by both threads.

Obviously, if you want simultaneous traversals, `markNodeVisited` has to record the "marks" in a way that each traversal uses an *independent* mark set.  That is a given.

Here's the problem for getting "accurate" counts.

- If the graph is being mutated, then you can only get sums that are instantaneously accurate if you can either block mutations or (effectively) snapshot the graph.  Obviously, the getters need to be synchronized etc to avoid memory anomalies resulting from mutation during or prior to the traversal.
- If the graph is not being mutated, then it is simply a matter of *reading* the node information in a thread-safe fashion.  Making the relevant getters synchronized should be sufficient.

In summary - unless you are clear in your specification of the expected (non-threaded) behavior, what the threads are doing, and unless you provide the rest of the code, we can't really give you an answer on how to make the code thread-safe.

---

Thread-safety is defined in terms of correctness.  Basically, it means that code that is correct when there is only one thread will also be correct when there are multiple threads.  This all hinges on what you *mean* by correct.  If you don't specify what "correct" means, "thread-safe" is not meaningful.

Comment: You're correct, I was not detailed enough in my description of the problem.  For the purposes of this question let's assume the graph is not being mutated.  I've updated the original problem description with this information.

Comment: In that case: 1) each traversal needs a private data structure to hold the marks. 2) either make the getters synchronized, or do something else to ensure that there is a memory barrier ("happens after" relationship) from the last graph update to the traversals.